# Python threads garbage collection

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection

Is a running thread eligable for garbage collection if the thread object is reasigned? For example:

```
class A(threading.Thread)
    def run():
        while True:
            #Do stuff


a = A()
a.start()
time.sleep(60)
a = A()
```

at this point, even though thread A is still doing stuff, can the interpreter destroy the original A() thread? If it does, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is no. There's still a reference to the thread in whatever structure Python uses to keep track of things. I'll test it out, but I'd be astonished if it didn't work.

**EDIT** Check it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading, time

class A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.name=name
            self.count=0
    def run(self):
            while self.count<10:
                    print self.name, "Running!"
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.count+=1

a=A("first")
a.start()
time.sleep(5)
a=A("second")
a.start()
```

```
first Running!
first Running!
first Running!
first Running!
first Running!
second Running!
first Running!
second Running!
first Running!
first Running!
second Running!
first Running!
second Running!
first Running!
second Running!
second Running!
second Running!
second Running!
second Running!
second Running!
```

Comment: I thought not too, and it seems to work. I'm just seeing weird errors (results in a database) that I thought might be explained by this. But I have no way of testing this case.

Comment: They won't get deleted, see `threading.enumerate()` - it gives a list of all threads.

Answer (score 4):

Threads wont get deleted like that, but I guess the problem you have is that threads disappear for no reason? A unhandled **Exception** will kill a thread without affecting the main thread! It only prints the traceback to stderr, but you might not see that ...

Answer (score 4):

Threads won't get garbage collected if there is a reference to the object kept somewhere.

see `https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py`, it keeps tabs on thread objects.

```
# Active thread administration
_active_limbo_lock = _allocate_lock()
_active = {}    # maps thread id to Thread object
_limbo = {}
```

The `threading` module keeps references in module variables. When you call `threading.enumerate()` you are iterating over the same variables.

When you call `start()` it inserts a reference to the `Thread` object in the module variable and when `run()` terminates, it cleans up the reference.