# Thread garbage collection

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection

Will a Python `threading.Thread` ever be garbage collected if there is no longer any reference to it but it's still running?

```
# Start a thread with no reference
Thread(target=some_long_running_function).start()
# Do lots of other stuff
```

Comment: I don’t know anything specifically to Python, but it would be very strange if a *running* thread suddenly disappears. What about the main thread in a single-threaded application, do you keep a reference to it all the time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threads garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494832/python-threads-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the Threading module contains a reference to the thread whilst it is running and is then cleaned when the Thread run() method has finished. I cannot comment on the internals of the module and how it accomplishes this but I believe these references (references to active threads) can be accessed via [threading.enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate)