# How do threads share references to an instance?

Tags: python

I am trying to wrap my head around Python multithreading by running some examples, and here is one whose behavior I don't quite understand

```
#!python3.6

import threading
import time

class ThreadClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.callback)
        self.thread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        print("DESTROYED")


    def callback(self):
        print("start second thread")
        print("second threadId=", threading.get_ident())
        print("self memory=", id(self))
        time.sleep(2)
        print("stop second thread")


def run():
    print("start first thread")
    print("first threadId=", threading.get_ident())
    thread = ThreadClass()
    print("threadClass memory=",id(thread))
    print("stop first thread")

run()
print("end")
```

The output I get is:

```
start first thread
first threadId= 140301467088640
start second thread
second threadId= 140301462193920
self memory= 140301465746680
threadClass memory= 140301465746680
stop first thread
end
stop second thread
DESTROYED
```

What I don't understand is why the ThreadClass instance is not destroyed as soon as the run() function ends. My understanding is that instance of ThreadClass is on the stack of run(), so when run() ends, should its stack be cleared & and the intstance deleted? But somehow that same instance of ThreadClass is left alive until another thread somewhere else in memory is done with it.

In other words, how does Python share memory between threads?

Comment: Try changing the `target=lambda: time.sleep(2)` and you'll see the `ThreadClass` instance is garbage collected first. In your example it can't be garbage collected since the running thread still holds a reference to it (to the `callback` method to be precise).

Answer (score 2):

A running thread (and its object) is never garbage collected (a daemon thread may be terminated with its process but that's something else).

The running thread object of your second thread (stored in `thread` of `ThreadClass` instance) references the `callback` method of a `ThreadClass` instance (because this method is executed in the thread) so the instance is needed while the thread is running.

Variables only contain references to objects, not objects itself. An object can only be garbage collected if no references to it exist anymore (except weak references).

At the end of `run()` only a reference was removed from stack.

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE* : The `def run()` as is in your code, it **irrelevant** to the class ThreadClass. Check your indentation and notice that the `run` is defined in module level, outside of the class.

In your code, as is, you start a second thread and you do not wait for it to finish. Therefore, the normal program (the `run()` as is) runs to the end, while the (second) thread is still running. Nothing weird on that, that's why threads are for; to run in parallel and async.

Furthermore, for the sake of full response, python does not guarantee any immediate garbage collection. If a variable is not referenced any more, there is nothing that will immediately release the memory, any handles, etc.
Therefore, the thread might not stop existing (and running), possibly until the whole python environment finishes. 
As an example put in [Thread garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052356/thread-garbage-collection) , the module threading will keep references to the threads.