# Python threading lifecycle

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading, django-celery

I am developing a Django project where after discarding the use of celery for its complexity, I have implemented python threading directly through the Thread class.
The purpose is very simple tasks that do not need a control if they have been carried out, such as sending push messages to devices (with a very low load, in the order of about 20 messages per hour). However I have been looking for multiple information about the Thread life cycle in python and I can come up with a conclusion about it.
Is it necessary to manually close each Thread launched or does the process end when the run function completes?
Not being necessary to control the correct execution of the operation, what advantages does the use of celery have over this option with the purpose and workload mentioned?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look at e.g. https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ instead of rolling your own background work system.

Comment: Beyond that, in general you don't want to launch a new thread for each task, but keep a pool of worker threads you distribute work to. One way to do that is the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool()` pool...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052356/thread-garbage-collection)

Comment: Huey seems like a good replacement for Celery but is still dependent on supervisord for his production run. With multiple parallel instances of Django, some in development, supervisord crashes are a stability issue. Regarding the use of enumerate(), it is a good resource to consult the active Threads, but I would like to know a little more about their internal workings in terms of their completion autonomously.